# How many trees does a forest with n vertices and m edges contain?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Concerning trees in graph theory:

> How many trees does a forest with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges contain?

This has to do with combinatorics apparently but I'm struggling with these assignments since we skipped that topic.

I'm thinking it's related to $m-1$ or $n-1$ something.

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you come up with some invariant using the number of nodes and edges for a single tree?

Comment: Remember that a tree with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First picture $n$ vertices with no edges. Then add the missing edges. Every time we add an edge, we combine two trees into one (as its vertices cannot come from the same tree - prove this). Therefore we end up with $n-m$ trees.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to go the other way around, i.e. how many edges does a forest with $k$ trees have ?

A tree with $n$ vertices has $n - 1$ edges.

Say your forest has $k$ trees.  Denote by $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k$ the number of vertices of each tree.  Thus the $i$-th tree has $n_i - 1$ edges.
Summing up, the total number of edges is

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^k (n_i - 1) = \sum_{i = 1}^k n_i - \sum_{i = 1}^k 1 = n - k
$$

So if the number of edges is $m$, we have $m = n - k$ and $k = n - m$.

Comment: One question, how come $\sum_{i = 1}^k - 1 = k$?

Comment: What this sum does is, for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$, add $-1$ to the sum.  In other words, you can rewrite this as $-1 + -1 + \ldots + -1$, exactly $k$ times.  So that's $-1 \cdot k = -k$.  But actually, there was a mistake in my answer.  I didn't need the minus in the summation.